# Fetch error "can't fetch" when submitting a form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, error-handling, fetch

Description: I am building a chatbot using React and OpenAI's GPT-3.5 and I am facing an issue with fetching data from my server. Whenever I click the "submit" button, I get a fetch error saying "can't fetch". I have checked my server and it seems to be running fine. Here is the relevant code:

Expected behavior: When I click the "submit" button, the server should respond with some data, which I can then use to update my React component.

Actual behavior: When I click the "submit" button, I get a fetch error saying "can't fetch".

Additional information: I am using Node.js v14.17.0, React v18.2.The CSS overflow property specifies whether to clip the content or to add scrollbars when the content of an element overflows the element's box. Here is a brief explanation of the values that this property can

```
// App.js

import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const getMessages = async () => {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "Hello ! How you doing?",
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:8000/completions",
        options
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="button-section">
        <div className="input-container">
          <input />
          <div id="submit" onClick={getMessages}>
            ➢
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

// server.js

const PORT = 8000;
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const api = "MY_API_KEY";

app.post("/completions", async (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer  ${api} `,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: "how are you?" }],
      max_tokens: 100,
    }),
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
      options
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    res.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log("Your server is running on PORT faizan " + PORT)
);
```

Comment: Can you add `console.log()` in the server side method and confirm you are receiving the response successfully?

Comment: Welcome to the community @faizan_khatib!  When putting keypresses or buttons in your questions, you can format them to stand out more by surrounding them with the `<kbd>` and `</kbd>` tags, e.g. your "submit" button. (Unfortunately, they don't work in comments, so I can't give you a demo in this.)

Comment: i add a console.log() it is printing in backend terminal but not in browser console.